# How can i increase size of swap file?

Tags: 14.04, swap

I'm new to Ubuntu . I need to increase size of swap file from 8 GB to 16 GB , how can i do it ? and is that in this file `/etc/fstab` ?

by command `free -h`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7.6G       4.8G       2.8G       623M       232M       2.5G
-/+ buffers/cache:       2.1G       5.5G
Swap:          15G         0B        15G
```

Comment: do you want to use the swap file or a swap partition? either is acceptable, but I believe the partition is more efficient. how ever increasing your partition size requires a live boot, because you partitions have to be unmounted to resize them.

Comment: i want to try sawp file . but if i used it , is that a problem ?

Comment: OK, first of all,  you've asked [same question](https://askubuntu.com/q/931128/295286) a few hours ago. There were multiple links provided that explain how to do it. Have you even looked at them ? Have you tried any of the methods provided there ?

Comment: yes , but i thought that s a separate question .. my previous post was closed so i re-opened a new one with a different question  and sorry if i didn't any mistake

Comment: @Sergiy -- heynnema asked him to open anew question so he could post detailed instructions.  but I got him through it in chat

Comment: @ravery   OK. I'll add my answer anyway

Comment: OK, I posted an answer. It's a custom-written script for adding swap. You don't have to do anything special in command line, just run the script with integer amount of swap that you want to add and that's it

Answer (score 3):

To make things easier, here's a script that I've written before, but modified for your question. This makes it easy to add desired amount of swap with a single command. It can be also found on my [personal github repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep), which may include additional fixes and updates.

Steps to set it up:

1. Copy the script presented below
2. Save it as file somewhere in come directory. Name it `addswap.sh`
3. Open terminal and do `cd <directory where you saved the script>`
4. Run `chmod +x ./addswap.sh`

Usage is very simple:

```
sudo ./addswap.sh INTEGER LETTER
```

For adding 1 gigabyte you would do `sudo ./addswap.sh 1 G`. For adding 1 megabyte do `sudo ./addswap.sh 1 M`.

#### Script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # bail if anything goes wrong

is_root(){
   if [ "$( id -u )" -ne 0  ] ; then
      return 1
   fi
   return 0
}

get_swap_amount(){
    # Obtain amount of swap in Gigabytes
    awk '/SwapTotal/{printf "%.2f",($2/1048576)}' /proc/meminfo
}

make_swap_file(){ 
   # This is the function that does the job of creatig swap file
   # and enabling it.  All files are timestamped
   printf "Current swap ammount: %f\n" "$(get_swap_amount)"
   printf "Working on creating swap file\n"
   DATE=$(date +%s) # append date of creation to filename
   filename="/swapfile.""$DATE" # File will be /swapfile.$DATE
   dd if=/dev/zero  of="$filename" bs=1"$2" count="$1"
   chmod 600 "$filename"
   mkswap "$filename" && 
   swapon "$filename" && 
   printf "\nCreated and turned on %s\n"  "$filename"
   printf "Current swap ammount: %f" "$(get_swap_amount)"
}


ask_to_enable_on_boot(){
   # Prompt user to enable this new swap file on boot. If user
   # enters y, the swap file will be added to /etc/fstab
   printf "Do you want to turn on this file at boot?[y/n]\n"
   read ANSWER
   case "$ANSWER" in
    [Yy]) printf "\n%s none swap defaults 0 0\n" "$filename"  >> /etc/fstab &&
       printf "\n %s added to /etc/fstab successfuly\n" "$filename"
       exit 0 ;;
    [Nn]) printf "Exiting\n" && exit 0 ;;
    *) printf "Wrong input: %s . Exiting. /etc/fstab not altered\n" "$ANSWER" && exit 1 ;;
   esac

}

bad_arguments(){
     # check if second argument is a character 
     case "$2" in 
         [A-Z]) return 1;;
         *) return 0;;
     esac

    # Check if first argument is a digit. 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951175/3701431
    case "$1" in
        ''|*[!0-9]*) return 0;;
        *) return 1 ;;
    esac 

}

main(){

    # Check if we're root and if args are OK. If everything is ok, do stuff

    if is_root 
    then
        if [ $# -ne 2   ] ||  bad_arguments "$@"
        then
            printf "%s\n" ">>> ERR: $0: bad or insufficient arguments" > /dev/stderr
            printf "%s\n" ">>> Usage: $0 INTEGER LETTER" > /dev/stderr
            exit 2
        fi
        make_swap_file "$@" && ask_to_enable_on_boot
    else
        printf ">>> ERR: $0 must run as root\n" > /dev/stderr
        exit 1
    fi
}

main "$@"
```

#### Test run

```
$ sudo ./addswap.sh 1 G                                                                                                                                                                 
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
Current swap ammount: 4.000000
Working on creating swap file
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 6.83322 s, 157 MB/s
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1024 MiB (1073737728 bytes)
no label, UUID=8bf1d78d-0a8a-478b-a783-38c5935c362f

Created and turned on /swapfile.1498976162
Current swap ammount: 5.000000Do you want to turn on this file at boot?[y/n]
Y

 /swapfile.1498976162 added to /etc/fstab successfuly
 $
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I need to increase it to 16 I can use  ./addswap.sh 16 G

Comment: @prog yes, you can do that

Comment: thanks for help , but i've problem i used this command to test if swap file is already now contains 16 GB or not `free -h `. and i got what i edited in the post . But the code which i want to increase memory for it still doesn't use this additional memory because i ran the command during my code running and found the used space are zero