# Can't add space in my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS partition

Tags: partitioning, swap

I have done dual boot on my laptop. And I have these partitions as shown in the figure.
[image: partitions image]

In this 25 GB partition, I have ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installed, and the 22 GB is Linux swap type and is empty, I want to add this 22 GB in my 25 GB partition because whenever I use ubuntu it shows a message of low storage. Tell me is there any way to perform this task?

This is my output of `swapon --show`:
[image: swapon --show output]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Are you actually not using the swap partition? Please [edit] your post to add the output of the command `swapon --show` (see also [How do I find out if I have a swap partition on my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/q/159783/250300)). Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text. See also [How much swap should I take for 1GB to 8TB of RAM on 14.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/594054/250300) for recommended swap sizes.

Comment: i have attached the output of swapon --show output.Kindly check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [Swap partition to Swap file](https://askubuntu.com/q/934679/)

Comment: @Melebius The OP doesn't need a swap partition in 20.04 anymore if he switches from swap partition to swap file. I also linked to a swap partition to Swap file question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much swap should I take for 1GB to 8TB of RAM on 14.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-8tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher) @karel I agree this is a way but OP hasn’t determined their optimal swap size yet. What if their RAM size is 16GB and wants to use hibernation?

Comment: Someone else has to add the other duplicate links because I can only add one duplicate link to this question.