# Very slow boot on 20.04 - verify fstab or other alternatives

Tags: boot, 20.04, mount, fstab

My Lenovo Thinkpad running Ubuntu 20.04 has started to take forever to boot. I read that it might be due to it trying for a long time to mount a partition that no longer exists in /etc/fstab but I'm not sure how I can verify it. My fstab currently looks like this (uncommented lines only):

```
UUID=31fad817-9f1c-4405-a552-8562c0e51c7d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=E244-61F0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile
```

How can I verify if this is correct? Is there anything else I can try to speed up the boot?

Comment: My swap file looks like this: `  /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0` It looks like you are missing the extra required fields in a fstab entry. see also `man fstab` for fields required.

Comment: Not sure what the /swapfile does, could I remove it or should I try to fill the line?

Comment: I would edit fstab. and after edit `sudo mount -a` if no error edit is good. the swap file is now the default install with Ubuntu. It used to use a swap partition. Swap is a fallback way to prevent system from crashing when you run out of RAM. When RAM was a lot smaller, swap was used a lot. Some with lots of RAM do not use swap, but risk a crash if some process runs away. Depends on how much RAM you have. https://askubuntu.com/questions/934679/swap-partition-to-swap-file