# Change swap file to swap partition - can this be done easily?

Tags: swap

I found many posts how to change a swap partition to a file e.g.: [Swap partition to Swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934679/swap-partition-to-swap-file). Due to some hibernate issues with LUbuntu I'd like to change my swap file to a partition. Can this be done or does it require a fresh install?

In case of yes: which steps do I have to do?

Thank you!

Comment: You stop using *swapfile* and switch to *swap partition*, use both, or change from *partition* to *swapfile*. All you need to do is add a swap partition using available space OR shrink a partition to create space, create a swap partition, then tell your system to use it.  No re-install is required

Comment: Why ? Swap-file is much more flexible than swap-partition.

Comment: Soren A: My intention is to make hibernate working on my LUbuntu tablet.
Spent some time and I saw a guide that involved swap-partition so I thought it might be mandatory for hibernate.

>...much more flexible than swap-partition...
Thanks for your input!
Looks like this might work too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a swap (or any) partition on a disk, none of the disk's partitions can be `mount`ed. Boot from a Live Cd, or your installation medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode.

Run `gparted`, make sure (in the upper right corner of `gparted`'s screen) you're manipulating the correct disk.

Use `gparted` to move/resize partitions to create available space as big as you want your swap to be.

Create a partition in the available space, format it as 'swap'.

Boot back into your normal system.

Use `blkid` to find the UUID, read `man fstab` to see how to add swap to `/etc/fstab`.

Then `swapon` your new partition,

`swapoff` and `rm` your swapfile.

Comment: Thank you for your guide!

Comment: @ssssstut Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.