# I have a swap partition but no swap space

Tags: swap

I have a 27.8G swap partition; though I have no swap space, I'd like to change that.

Here is the pertinent output from `top`.

```
KiB Swap:  0 total,  0 free,  0 used
```

I believe I may have turned it off with the `swapoff --all`. That being said the `swapon --all` exits with `swapon: /dev/sda6: swapon failed: Invalid argument`.

Here is the swap entry in my `/etc/fstab`

```
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=aa0cdc90-ef01-446b-a6a2-fac368d16aca none swap defaults 0 0
```

I affirmed the UUID of my partition with the one in `/etc/fstab`.
Below is the output from `blkid`.

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6: UUID="aa0cdc90-ef01-446b-a6a2-fac368d16aca" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6ddd3267-3895-40e5-9acc-56bfbc58039b"
```

My swap partiton is on `/dev/sda6` not `/dev/sdb6`.
I presume `/dev/sdb6` was the bootable USB I used to install the system.
This is a dual-booted, single-drive system.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you append the output of `sudo blkid` to our question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I appended the `blkid` output.

Comment: Your entry in `/etc/fstab` appears to be wrong. Try changing it to `/dev/sda6         none         swap          defaults         0      0` or `UUID=aa0cdc90-ef01-446b-a6a2-fac368d16aca none         swap          defaults         0      0`

Comment: Your PARTUUID looks odd for a partition of ID=82 type =Linux swap / Solaris. What does sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda6 |grep sda6  show?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thanks for the suggestion. Neither of those worked, unfortunately.

Comment: @ubfan1 `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda6 | grep sda6` outputs 
`Disk /dev/sda6: 27.8 GiB, 29877683712 bytes, 58354851 sectors`

Comment: @Inquisitor This seems very odd. For the time being, create a swap file. I've a script to perform such task in easy manner, https://askubuntu.com/a/931170/295286 There's manual instructions on linked duplicate as well. As for your partition, give it some time. If you don't find a solution here, consider deleting that partition and sticking with swap file only, or reformatting that partition. Also, it may be worth checking hard drive health. If there is large number of bad blocks, it's time to abandon the drive.

Comment: Oops, sorry, that should have been sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda |grep sda6  to get the id and type.

Comment: @uban1 `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep sda6` outputs `/dev/sda6  429926400 488281250  58354851  27.8G Linux swap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the swap space may have never been turned on since initialising the OS.

The problem was solved by running `mkswap` and then `swapon` on the partition.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever changed it? Maybe you didn't set your swap. Personally, I recommend you use Gparted to edit your swap again.

You can install Gparted in your terminal or I have written an answer here - [How to install Gparted(iso)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399784/unable-to-start-gparted/492743#492743). After that, the swap won't show up because it is not active.

Type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

add:

```
/swap/swapfile  swap      swap    defaults   0       0
```

reboot, and see if it is all right:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

Comment: `/swap/swapfile` has to exist first in order to be added. Also reboot is unnecessary, `swapon` command is sufficient

Comment: Yeah,you are right.Just change the UUID will be all right.:)...I'll try not reboot next time,I always reboot after I edit about the disk partition...&_&